# Jpeg DCT compression of the same color

Tags: jpeg, dct

If a 8x8 matrix contain only one color will the compression be greater than if it had many different colors? Does the number of different colors in a 8x8 matrix affect the number of 0s generated from the DCT?

I mean If I have for example 8 bits for color, but my matrix happens to have only the color black0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of different colours isn't really a great measure, because their arrangement is very important as well. But when there's only 1 colour, there's also only 1 arrangement, so it doesn't make any difference.

The DCT of a constant will have zeroes for all the AC coefficients. It may have a non-zero DC coefficient, but it could also be zero (the DCT of zero is of course zero, philosophically it's a basis change and the zero vector will be the zero vector in any basis - that's about the zero you put into the DCT, not zero as in black).

In other cases, it doesn't work out like that. For example, it's better to have a gradient than to have a sharp transition (if the transition is between blocks it's fine, but across a block will cost a lot of AC coefficients to code). So for example, a "gradient" using 2 colours (not really a gradient, more of a step function) costs many more AC coefficients than a smooth gradient using 8 different colours. And arranging those 8 colours randomly again costs many AC coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the nature of the color variations and the quantization table used.

The output from the DCT depends, on the number of different component values,  their position within the DCT input matrix, and the values themselves (how far they are from the mean within the block).

In general, an 8x8 block of one component value will compress better than one with multiple values. However, the values that are compressed are the quantized DCT values. If the quantized DCT AC coefficients are all zero, then it's effectively the same as a block of a single color.